# OpenSSL EVP_DigestSignFinal makes the pointer NULL in gcc/linux

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc, openssl

I'm writing an OpenSSL program which contains the following code for generating HMAC value

```
void hmac_message(unsigned char* msg, size_t mlen, unsigned char** val, size_t* vlen, unsigned char *key)
{
  EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = NULL;
  const EVP_MD* md = NULL;
  EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

  if(!(mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()))
    handleErrors();

  if(!(md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256")))
    handleErrors();

  if(!(pkey = EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key(EVP_PKEY_HMAC, NULL, key, EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256()))))
    handleErrors();

  if(1 != EVP_DigestSignInit(mdctx, NULL, md, NULL, pkey))
    handleErrors();

  /* Call update with the message */
  int md_len = 0;
  if(1 != EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mdctx, msg, mlen))
    handleErrors();

  if(((*val) = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256()))) == NULL)
    handleErrors();
  printf("msg %s\n", msg);

  if(*val == NULL) {
    printf("Null Pointer error!\n");
  }
  printf("1: %p\n", *val);
  if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, *val, vlen))
    handleErrors();
  printf("2: %p\n", *val);
  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, *val, 32);

  EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
  EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

  return;
}
```

And I use travis CI to test it, however I always get this result:

> msg www.google.com
>
> 1: 0x1fd7a20
>
> 2: (nil)
>
> /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 57:  3821 Segmentation fault

Which means the *val pointer is set to NULL, that shouldn't be happening.

The code works perfectly on my mac and on gcc/OSX, clang/OSX, clang/linux on travis, only fails on gcc/linux. I tried different version of gcc like 4.9/5/6 they all get the same result.

**EDIT**:
I tried adding output for MD_SIZE and the result is

> MD SIZE: 32
>
> msg www.google.com
>
> 1: 0xbb7a20
>
> 2: (nil)
>
> /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 57:  3860 Segmentation fault

This is really weird.

**EDIT on 9/7/2017**

I tried editing the code to declare a local pointer variable and do all the stuff above, and set the local variable value to `*val` then everything works well. This is super weird, why this happens under gcc/linux remains a mystery. If anyone has some ideas about the reason, please post an answer.

Comment: Remember that segmentation faults happen for pointers to *any* unmapped page, not just NULL.

Comment: @o11c Correct, but when I print the pointer value it says (nil), what might cause this?

Comment: OPENSSL_malloc appears to fail, have you checked EVP_MD_size returns non zero value that you are passing to OPENSSL_malloc

Comment: `*vlen` should be initialised to the amount of data that you have malloc'd (i.e. `EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256())`, *before* you call EVP_DigestSignFinal

Comment: @Pras Yes I just did a check and the output seems fine(see the edit), by the way the first print for the pointer value proves that the pointer has got successfully allocated because I pass the pointer val to the function by calling like `unsigned char * ptr = NULL; hmac_message(..., &ptr, ...);`

Comment: @MattCaswell Isn't `OPENSSL_malloc` doing this for me?

Comment: The first time you use `vlen` in your code is in the EVP_DigestSignFinal() call, so how could OPENSSL_malloc() have set it for you?

Comment: @MattCaswell Sorry I mistook it for `val`, yes I added a line setting the `*vlen` to `EVP_MD_size(EVP_sha256())` and I still got the same result.

Comment: @o11c @Pras @MattCaswell Guys, I tried editing the code to declare a local pointer variable and do all the stuff above, and set the local variable value to `*val` then everything works well. This is super weird, why this happens under gcc/linux remains a mystery.